# What is the distribution of $(X,Y)|Y$?

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given $(X,Y)$ is an $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued random vector, what is the distribution of $(X,Y)|Y$? I thought it is the same as the distribution of $X|Y$, but wanted to double check.

Comment: Some people will object to the notation $(X,Y)\mid Y$ and $X\mid Y$ saying that these are not events in the original probability space.  Even skipping over that point, these would not be the same since $(X,Y) \in \mathbb R^2$ and $X \in \mathbb R$.  To deal with both issues, you are going to have to restate this with meaningful notation: remember that things like $\mathbb E[X \mid Y]$ and  $\mathbb P[X>7 \mid Y]$ are functions of $Y$ even if you know the joint distribution

Comment: I'm not sure why we need to specify the original probability space. The implicit assumption when we talk about distributions of random variables is that we are using the induced probability measure: $P_X(A)\equiv \mathbb{P} (X^{-1} (A) )\forall$ measurable $A$. Let's take a concrete case of $(X,Y)$ being bivariate normal; we can certainly talk about $X|Y$ (a well-known result).  So what can we say in that case about $(X,Y)|Y$?

Comment: The argument is that if you say $\mathbb P(X \in A \mid Y)$ you are applying  $\mathbb P(\cdot  \mid Y)$ to the event $X \in A$ not $\mathbb P(\cdot )$ to $ X \in A \mid Y$ as that is not an event